# Using Google Analytics to track Persistent Shopping Conversions

Tags: magento-1.7, google-analytics, persistent, conversion

When enabling Persist Shopping in Magento, is it at all possible to track the effectiveness thereof using Google Analytics.

I'm thinking somewhere along the lines of using the [URL builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) and appending these parameters to the URL used when activating the persistent session.

I've looked through the `config.xml` and can see quite a few event-observers. Would it be possible to create a local override & modify the observer model to accommodate the Analytics tracking?

Comment: If you want to go the extension route, I'm sure these guys would add it for you, plus it has a bunch of rich GA features.  http://restaurant.web-cooking.net/seo/magento-google-universal-analytics.html  I just put this as a comment since, it's more a suggestion than an answer.